# Appscript code to replace the existing google doc file with the new file's content

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This code reads the name of the file in the sheet, check the file option yes/no, if option is 'yes' it checks for the particular file in the given folder and if option is 'No' it skips that file. The files in the given folder are shortcuts of original files. The original files are updated every week and the shortcuts are auto updated. But the files in destination folder are not updated.

I am writing this code to replace the content of existing file in destination folder with the content of new file. I could have deleted the old file and replaced with new one but the old file is syncing in another app. If I replace that with new file, the file ID will change and the sync will stop. So, I am trying to replace the content of old file with new file. But this code is not working properly. Instead of overwriting the content, it just remove everything and add the 'Blob' word in the exiting file. Please give me some idea. Sorry for my language. Thank you!!!!

```
function copyPolicies() {
  var spreadsheetId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Replace with your spreadsheet ID
  var sheetName = 'xxxxxxx'; // Replace with your sheet name
  var folderId = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // Replace with your folder ID
  var destinationFolderId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Replace with your destination folder ID 
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);

  var fileArray = []; // Array to store filenames and file objects

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var fileNameYes = data[i][1]; // Assuming the file names for "Yes" option are in the second column
    var fileNameNo = data[i][0]; // Assuming the file names for "No" option are in the first column
    var option = data[i][4]; // Assuming the drop-down options are in the fifth column (index 4)

    if (option === 'Yes') { // Modify 'Yes' to match the option value in your drop-down                                                                               
      var files = folder.getFilesByName(fileNameYes);

      while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        
        if (file.getMimeType() === MimeType.SHORTCUT) {
          var targetFileId = file.getTargetId();
          var targetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(targetFileId);
          
          // Check if a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder
          var existingFiles = destinationFolder.getFilesByName(fileNameYes);
          if (existingFiles.hasNext()) {
            var existingFile = existingFiles.next();
            existingFile.setContent(targetFile.getBlob()); // Overwrite the content of the existing file
          } else {
            // Create a new copy of the file in the destination folder
            var newFile = targetFile.makeCopy(destinationFolder);
            
            // Set the copied file's name to the original file name
            newFile.setName(fileNameYes);
            
            fileArray.push({
              name: fileNameYes, // Store the file name
              file: newFile // Store the copied file
            });
          }
        }
      }
      
      if (!fileArray.length) {
        Logger.log('File "' + fileNameYes + '" is missing in the given folder or is not a shortcut.');
      }
    } else if (option === 'No') { // Modify 'No' to match the option value in your drop-down
      Logger.log('Skipping file "' + fileNameNo + '". Option is set to "No".');
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to copy every content of the new file to the old file like images, tables and texts but nothing were overwritten. It just remove the content of old file and add 'Blob' word in the file.

Comment: You are using `setContent(content)` to replace the content of the existing file; the `content` parameter is a string. [Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file?hl=en#setcontentcontent) and script parameter is `targetFile.getBlob()`. You've told us nothing about the content of these files, but why not try `targetFile.getBlob().getDataAsString()` as a test?

Comment: As additional comment, can you provide the mimeTypes of `existingFile` and `targetFile`?

Comment: @Tedinoz the contents are policies which contain images, tables, texts, heading, page numbers and so on. I can copy the text, tables etc by other methods too but I am having issue with copying images specifically. The background image doesn't load. I can provide my another code if you want to see.

Comment: @Tanaike the given folder have shortcuts of original google docs, the existing files are google docs files. So, I need to have the content of shortcuts replace the content in google docs without changing the file ID.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, Google Document cannot be directly overwritten by another Google Document. In this case, it is required to overwrite the target Google Document by DOCX data converted from the source Google Document. But, Google Document is different from DOCX data. For example, when you are using the smart chips, those cannot be restored by overwritten. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the perfect overwrite cannot be achieved. I'm worried about this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, as a workaround, when the structure of the Google Document body is always the same, your goal might be able to be achieved by copying each content into Google Document. But, I'm worried that in this case, the complexity of the script depends on the structure of the Google Document body. But, in this case, also, the smart chips might not be able to be correctly copied.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your response. I knew that from Google support that it is not possible to achieve the perfect result as appscript have problem working with images and formatting. I was looking if someone know the workaround. I will do the things manually now. Thank you for confirmation that this feature is still not available.